# Converting GCC assembly code to armasm assembly code

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm, using-directives

I am trying to convert GCC assembly code to ARMASM assembly code can anyone please help me with this.  The main problem is .req .unreq .qn.dn . I wanted to know the equivalents of the above directives. I tried ALIAS it did not work.

```
 .align   4
.global   ne10_fir_float_neon
.extern   ne10_qMaskTable32
.thumb
.thumb_func

ne10_fir_float_neon:
PUSH    {r4-r12,lr}    @push r12:
to keep stack 8 bytes aligned
@/*ARM Registers*/
pStateStruct     .req   R0
pSrc             .req   R1
pDst             .req   R2
blockSize        .req   R3

pState           .req   R4             @/* State pointer */
pCoeffs          .req   R5             @/* Coefficient pointer */
pStateCurnt      .req   R6             @/* Points to the current sample of the state */

pX               .req   R7             @/* Temporary pointers for state buffer */
pB               .req   R8             @/* Temporary pointers for coefficient buffer */
numTaps          .req   R9             @/* Length of the filter */

tapCnt           .req   R10            @ /* Loop counter */
Count            .req   R11            @ /* Loop counter */
pTemp            .req   R11
pMask            .req   R14            @  /* Mask Table */

mask             .req   R12

@/*NEON variale Declaration*/
qInp             .qn   Q0.F32
dInp_0           .dn   D0.F32
dInp_1           .dn   D1.F32
qCoeff           .qn   Q1.F32
dCoeff_0         .dn   D2.F32
dCoeff_1         .dn   D3.F32
qZero            .qn   Q2.F32

qMask            .qn   Q3.U32
dMask_0          .dn   D6.U32
dMask_1          .dn   D7.U32
dOut_0           .dn   D6.F32
dOut_1           .dn   D7.F32

qAcc0            .qn   Q8.F32
dAcc0_0          .dn   D16.F32
dAcc0_1          .dn   D17.F32


qTemp            .qn   Q9.F32
dTemp_0          .dn   D18.F32
dTemp_1          .dn   D19.F32

qTemp1           .qn   Q10.F32
dTemp1_0         .dn   D20.F32
dTemp1_1         .dn   D21.F32
qTemp2           .qn   Q11.F32
qTemp3           .qn   Q12.F32
qMask1           .qn   Q13.U32
dMask1_0         .dn   D26.U32
dMask1_1         .dn   D27.U32
qMaskTmp         .qn   Q14.U32
dMaskTmp_0       .dn   D28.U32
dMaskTmp_1       .dn   D29.U32

qAcc1            .qn   Q3.F32
qAcc2            .qn   Q13.F32
qAcc3            .qn   Q15.F32




LDRH        numTaps,[pStateStruct],#4
LDR         pState,[pStateStruct],#4
LDR         pCoeffs,[pStateStruct],#4

@/* S->state buffer contains previous frame (numTaps - 1) samples */
@/* pStateCurnt points to the location where the new input data should be written */
@/*pStateCurnt = &(S->state[(numTaps - 1u)])@*/
SUB         mask,numTaps,#1
LDR         pMask,=ne10_qMaskTable32
                   AND         tapCnt,numTaps,#3
                   ADD         pStateCurnt,pState,mask,LSL #2
                   AND         mask,blockSize,#3


                   @/* Apply loop unrolling and compute 4 output values simultaneously.
                    @* The variables acc0 ... acc3 hold output values that are being computed:
                    @*
                    @*    acc0 =  b[numTaps-1] * x[n-numTaps-1] + b[numTaps-2] * x[n-numTaps-2] + b[numTaps-3] * x[n-numTaps-3] +...+ b[0] * x[0]
                    @*    acc1 =  b[numTaps-1] * x[n-numTaps] +   b[numTaps-2] * x[n-numTaps-1] + b[numTaps-3] * x[n-numTaps-2] +...+ b[0] * x[1]
                    @*    acc2 =  b[numTaps-1] * x[n-numTaps+1] + b[numTaps-2] * x[n-numTaps] +   b[numTaps-3] * x[n-numTaps-1] +...+ b[0] * x[2]
                    @*    acc3 =  b[numTaps-1] * x[n-numTaps+2] + b[numTaps-2] * x[n-numTaps+1] + b[numTaps-3] * x[n-numTaps]   +...+ b[0] * x[3]
                    @*/

                   @/*If numTaps,blockSize are not  multiples of 4,  Get the appropriate Masks*/


                   ADD         pTemp,pMask,tapCnt,LSL #4
                   VEOR        qZero,qZero
                   ADD         pX,pMask,mask,LSL #4
                   VLD1        {dMaskTmp_0,dMaskTmp_1},[pTemp]
                   VLD1        {dMask1_0,dMask1_1},[pX]


                   @/* Copy blockCnt number of  new input samples into the state buffer */

                   SUBS        blockSize,#4
                   BLT         firEndOuterLoop

                   @/* Compute 4 outputs at a time*/

                   firOuterLoop:

                   VLD1        {dTemp_0,dTemp_1},[pSrc]!
                   MOV         pX,pState
                   MOV         pB,pCoeffs
                   @/* Read the first four samples from the state buffer:
                    @* x[n-numTaps], x[n-numTaps-1], x[n-numTaps-2],x[n-numTaps-3] */

                   VST1        {dTemp_0,dTemp_1},[pStateCurnt]!
                   @/* Zero the Accumulators*/
                   VEOR        qAcc0,qAcc0
                   VLD1        {dInp_0,dInp_1},[pX]!

                   @//* Read the first four coefficients b[numTaps] to b[numTaps-3] */
                   VLD1        {dCoeff_0,dCoeff_1},[pB]!
                   @/* Loop unrolling.  Process 4 taps at a time. */
                   SUBS        tapCnt,numTaps,#4
                   VLD1        {dTemp_0,dTemp_1},[pX]!

                   BLT         firEndInnerLoop

                   firInnerLoop:
                   VEXT        qTemp1,qInp,qTemp,#1
                   @/* acc0 +=  b[numTaps] * x[n-numTaps-1]+ b[numTaps] * x[n-numTaps-2] +
                    @* b[numTaps] * x[n-numTaps-3] +  b[numTaps] * x[n-numTaps-4]*/
                   VMLA        qAcc0,qInp,dCoeff_0[0]
                   @/* acc1 +=  b[numTaps-1] * x[n-numTaps-2]+ b[numTaps-1] * x[n-numTaps-3] +
                    @b[numTaps-1] * x[n-numTaps-4] +*b[numTaps-1] * x[n-numTaps-5]*/
                   VMUL        qAcc1,qTemp1,dCoeff_0[1]

                   VEXT        qTemp2,qInp,qTemp,#2
                   @/* acc2 +=  b[numTaps-2] * x[n-numTaps-3]+ b[numTaps-2] * x[n-numTaps-4] +
                    @b[numTaps-2] * x[n-numTaps-5] + *b[numTaps-2] * x[n-numTaps-6]*/
                   VMUL        qAcc2,qTemp2,dCoeff_1[0]
                   VADD        qAcc0, qAcc0, qAcc1

                   VEXT        qTemp3,qInp,qTemp,#3
                   @/* acc3 +=  b[numTaps-3] * x[n-numTaps-4]+ b[numTaps-3] * x[n-numTaps-5] +
                    @b[numTaps-3] * x[n-numTaps-6] +*b[numTaps-3] * x[n-numTaps-7]  */
                   VMUL        qAcc3,qTemp3,dCoeff_1[1]
                   VADD        qAcc0, qAcc0, qAcc2

                   VMOV        qInp,qTemp
                   VLD1        {dTemp_0,dTemp_1},[pX]!
                   VADD        qAcc0, qAcc0, qAcc3

                   SUBS        tapCnt,#4
                   @/* Read the b[numTaps-4] to b[numTaps-7]  coefficients */
                   VLD1        {dCoeff_0,dCoeff_1},[pB]!


                   BGE         firInnerLoop
                   firEndInnerLoop:

                   ADDS        tapCnt, tapCnt, #4
                   BEQ         firStoreOutput

                   @/* If the filter length is not a multiple of 4, compute the remaining filter taps */
                   @/*Select only the remaining filter Taps*/
                   VMOV        qMask,qMaskTmp
                   VBSL        qMask,qCoeff,qZero
                   VEXT        qTemp1,qInp,qTemp,#1
                   VMLA        qAcc0,qInp,dOut_0[0]
                   VEXT        qTemp2,qInp,qTemp,#2
                   VMLA        qAcc0,qTemp1,dOut_0[1]
                   VMLA        qAcc0,qTemp2,dOut_1[0]

                   firStoreOutput:
                   @/* Advance the state pointer by 4 to process the next group of 4 samples */
                   ADD         pState,#16

                   @/* The results in the 4 accumulators are in 2.30 format.  Convert to 1.31
                    @ * Then store the 4 outputs in the destination buffer. */
                   SUBS        blockSize,#4
                   VST1        {dAcc0_0,dAcc0_1},[pDst]!

                   BGE         firOuterLoop

                   firEndOuterLoop:
                   @/*Handle BlockSize Not a Multiple of 4*/
                   ADDS        blockSize,#4
                   BEQ         firCopyData
                   @/*Copy the Remaining BlockSize Number of Input Sample to state Buffer*/
                   VMOV        qMask,qMask1
                   VLD1        {dTemp1_0,dTemp1_1},[pStateCurnt]
                   VLD1        {dTemp_0,dTemp_1},[pSrc]

                   ADD         pSrc,pSrc,blockSize,LSL #2
                   MOV         pX,pState
                   MOV         pB,pCoeffs

                   VBSL        qMask,qTemp,qTemp1
                   VST1        {dMask_0,dMask_1},[pStateCurnt]
                   VLD1        {dInp_0,dInp_1},[pX]!

                   ADD         pStateCurnt,pStateCurnt,blockSize, LSL #2

                   @/* Zero the Accumulators*/
                   VEOR        qAcc0,qAcc0
                   VLD1        {dCoeff_0,dCoeff_1},[pB]!
                   SUBS        tapCnt,numTaps,#4
                   VLD1        {dTemp_0,dTemp_1},[pX]!

                   BLT         firEndInnerLoop1

                   firInnerLoop1:

                   VEXT        qTemp1,qInp,qTemp,#1
                   VMLA        qAcc0,qInp,dCoeff_0[0]
                   VEXT        qTemp2,qInp,qTemp,#2
                   VMLA        qAcc0,qTemp1,dCoeff_0[1]
                   VEXT        qTemp3,qInp,qTemp,#3
                   VMLA        qAcc0,qTemp2,dCoeff_1[0]
                   VMOV        qInp,qTemp
                   VMLA        qAcc0,qTemp3,dCoeff_1[1]
                   VLD1        {dCoeff_0,dCoeff_1},[pB]!
                   SUBS        tapCnt,#4
                   VLD1        {dTemp_0,dTemp_1},[pX]!

                   BGE         firInnerLoop1
                   firEndInnerLoop1:


                   VMOV        qMask,qMaskTmp
                   VBSL        qMask,qCoeff,qZero
                   VEXT        qTemp1,qInp,qTemp,#1
                   VMLA        qAcc0,qInp,dOut_0[0]
                   VEXT        qTemp2,qInp,qTemp,#2
                   VMLA        qAcc0,qTemp1,dOut_0[1]
                   VMLA        qAcc0,qTemp2,dOut_1[0]
                   VMOV        qMask,qMask1
                   VLD1        {dTemp_0,dTemp_1},[pDst]


                   @/* If the blockSize is not a multiple of 4, Mask the unwanted Output */

                   VBSL        qMask,qAcc0,qTemp
                   VST1        {dMask_0,dMask_1},[pDst]
                   ADD         pDst,pDst,blockSize,LSL #2
                   ADD         pState,pState,blockSize,LSL #2


                   firCopyData:
                   @/* Processing is complete.  Now shift the data in the state buffer down by
                    @** blockSize samples.  This prepares the state buffer for the next function
                    @** call. */

                   @/* Points to the start of the state buffer */

                   SUB         numTaps,numTaps,#1
                   AND         mask,numTaps,#3
                   LDR         pStateCurnt,[pStateStruct,#-8]
                   ADD         pTemp,pMask,mask,LSL #4
                   VLD1        {dInp_0,dInp_1},[pState]!
                   VLD1        {dMask_0,dMask_1},[pTemp]


                   @/* copy data */

                   SUBS        Count,numTaps,#4
                   BLT         firEnd
                   firCopyLoop:
                   VST1        {dInp_0,dInp_1},[pStateCurnt]!
                   SUBS        Count,#4
                   VLD1        {dInp_0,dInp_1},[pState]!
                   BGE         firCopyLoop

                   firEnd:

                   VLD1        {dTemp_0,dTemp_1},[pStateCurnt]
                   VBSL        qMask,qInp,qTemp
                   VST1        {dOut_0,dOut_1},[pStateCurnt]
                   ADD         pStateCurnt,pStateCurnt,mask, LSL #2

                   @/*Return From Function*/
                   POP     {r4-r12,pc}
                   @/*ARM Registers*/
                   .unreq    pStateStruct
                   .unreq    pSrc
                   .unreq    pDst
                   .unreq    blockSize

                   .unreq    pState
                   .unreq    pCoeffs
                   .unreq    pStateCurnt

                   .unreq    pX
                   .unreq    pB
                   .unreq    numTaps

                   .unreq    tapCnt
                   .unreq    Count
                   .unreq    pTemp
                   .unreq    pMask

                   .unreq    mask

                   @/*NEON variale Declaration*/
                   .unreq    qInp
                   .unreq    dInp_0
                   .unreq    dInp_1
                   .unreq    qCoeff
                   .unreq    dCoeff_0
                   .unreq    dCoeff_1
                   .unreq    qZero

                   .unreq    qMask
                   .unreq    dMask_0
                   .unreq    dMask_1
                   .unreq    dOut_0
                   .unreq    dOut_1

                   .unreq    qAcc0
                   .unreq    dAcc0_0
                   .unreq    dAcc0_1

                   .unreq    qTemp
                   .unreq    dTemp_0
                   .unreq    dTemp_1

                   .unreq    qTemp1
                   .unreq    dTemp1_0
                   .unreq    dTemp1_1
                   .unreq    qTemp2
                   .unreq    qTemp3
                   .unreq    qMask1
                   .unreq    dMask1_0
                   .unreq    dMask1_1
                   .unreq    qMaskTmp
                   .unreq    dMaskTmp_0
                   .unreq    dMaskTmp_1

                   .unreq    qAcc1
                   .unreq    qAcc2
                   .unreq    qAcc3
                   .end
```

Comment: @BoPersson: I think he is converting between two assemblers for the same cpu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it .req is same as RN and made some adjustments and removed unnesaary directives got it working!!